# execute file every 10 minutes with azure

Tags: azure, task, execute

I'm new on azure and I want execute a program (.exe) every 10 minutes to fill my database.

<del>Please can you explain me how to do that ? I think I can do this creating virtual machine and execute my program with windows task but Azure may do better ? I hope..</del>

Have you an idea about the cost of this recursive operation ?

Edit : I published my application on azure with visual studio as a webjob but the task scheduler about 10 minutes crashed.

I read that we can't use a recursive task less than 1 hour with free package.
Is there a way to use the 10 minutes job with free plan ? maybe with a Cron expression

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Web jobs that can scheduled for any number of time.  
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/